# frame_dummy() causing seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I experienced segmentation fault and with gdb I found out :

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb771ca28 in frame_dummy () from /home/Dev/.libs/coap-1.so.0
```

and :

```
(gdb) i r
eax            0x0  0
ecx            0x81477bc    135559100
edx            0x378845d4   931677652
ebx            0xb772a000   -1217224704
esp            0xbfddbcd0   0xbfddbcd0
ebp            0x81477bc    0x81477bc
esi            0x0  0
edi            0xbfddbd88   -1075987064
eip            0xb771ca28   0xb771ca28 <frame_dummy+8>
eflags         0x10246  [ PF ZF IF RF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
```

What exactly causing this seg fault I am not getting.

EDIT :

compiler optimization is set to O0 
and got :

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb7792a90 in coap_address_equals (a=0xac6745d4, b=0x922b814) at src/address.c:20
20    if (a->size != b->size || a->addr.sa.sa_family != b->addr.sa.sa_family)
```

and with bt I got :

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7792a90 in coap_address_equals (a=0xac6745d4, b=0x922b814) at src/address.c:20
'#1  0xb779bd8c in coap_find_observer (resource=0x922b530, peer=0x922b814, token=0xbfd8d7a8) at src/resource.c:530
#2  0x0804c55b in hnd_get_cpufreq (ctx=0x92260c0, resource=0x922b530, local_interface=0x922b784, peer=0x922b814, request=0x0, token=0xbfd8d7a8, 
    response=0x9227ea0) at leshan_test.c:1413
#3  0xb779c2c1 in coap_notify_observers (context=0x92260c0, r=0x922b530) at src/resource.c:656
#4  0xb779c439 in coap_check_notify (context=0x92260c0) at src/resource.c:690
#5  0x08051cba in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfd8e304) at leshan_test.c:3571
```

With `(gdb) r i` I found :

```
/home/libcoap/examples/.libs/leshan_test: relocation error: /home/libcoap/examples/.libs/leshan_test: symbol coap_set_send_handler, version VER_1 not defined in file libcoap-1.so.0 with link time reference
[Inferior 1 (process 16434) exited with code 0177]
```

**EDIT :** 
disassemble dump : http://pastebin.com/6r3CuELd

**EDIT :**

```
(gdb) p *a
Cannot access memory at address 0xac6745d4
(gdb) p *b
$4 = {size = 0, addr = {sa = {sa_family = 0, sa_data = '\000' <repeats 13 times>}, st = {ss_family = 0, __ss_align = 0, 
      __ss_padding = '\000' <repeats 119 times>}, sin = {sin_family = 0, sin_port = 0, sin_addr = {s_addr = 0}, 
      sin_zero = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}, sin6 = {sin6_family = 0, sin6_port = 0, sin6_flowinfo = 0, sin6_addr = {__in6_u = {
          __u6_addr8 = '\000' <repeats 15 times>, __u6_addr16 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, __u6_addr32 = {0, 0, 0, 0}}}, sin6_scope_id = 0}}}
(gdb)
```

Comment: Make sure to build libcoap with debugging CFLAGS="-O0 -g". This makes backtraces easier in gdb (which you did not provide, command for that in gdb is bt). Also, if doing assembler, you should dump the assembler at the crashpoint. Just viewing the registers is not enough. gdb command disassemble

Comment: @StianSkjelstad Thanks, I had added info with optimization level zero.

Comment: @StianSkjelstad the disassemble dump is here : http://pastebin.com/6r3CuELd

Comment: when it crashes in coap_address_equals, you can tell gdb to inspect parameter a and b, by "p *a"  and "p *b".

I suspect that one of the pointers are just random garbage. Try to run your software via valgrind (a very nice memory diagnostics tools)

Comment: @StianSkjelstad memory of a is not accessible but b has the data

Comment: valgrind analysys showed : .libs/leshan_test: relocation error: .libs/leshan_test: symbol coap_set_send_handler, version VER_1 not defined in file libcoap-1.so.0 with link time reference

Comment: valgrind should show more information than that, pastebin the full output from valgrind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109802/discussion-between-stian-skjelstad-and-zim).